# Table view in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I have a `UICollectionView` with horizontal scrolling direction.
It has a button. On that button click i want to show a list `tableView`. My question is where should i implement table view delegate method,
in BasicVC, where i create `collectionView`,

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"cell", for: indexPath)
    let btn = c.viewWithTag(9) as? UIButton
    btn?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    btn?.layer.cornerRadius = (btn?.frame.size.height)!/2
    btn?.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
    return c
}
```

or in `collectionCell` class.

```
class PlayerHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!}
```

Comment: you need to display tableview in collectionview cell?

Comment: If you don't want tableview in cell , create another view controller with tableview and push / present it

Comment: If your tableview in collection view cell then you should implement delegate / datasoruce in uiviewcontroller subclass

Comment: You can try uipopoverpresentationcontroller

Answer (score 0):

`tableView` delegate methods needs to implemented in `UICollectionViewCell` like so

```
class PlayerHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell,  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a table view to popup on top of the collection view like a drop down menu right? If you're wanting to have a table view that is displayed over top your current view, I'd recommend creating a new view controller for it in your story board that contains the table view, and then presenting that controller on top of the current view. The result would be a table view floating wherever you want on top of your collection view.

Unlike what the other answer said, do NOT make the collection cell the table view delegate, it just doesn't make sense unless you want a different table view for every cell, in which case you should do this and set the delegate to be the selected collection cell.

To implement the popup table view:

1. Create a view controller in storyboard
2. Create a new table view, place it INSIDE the new view controllers default view (the default view is used as the background but will be invisible.)
3. Set view controller's presentation to be Over Content
4. Set the new view controllers background view to be completely transparent by changing its color
5. Ctrl drag from your previous view controller to your new view controller and create a modal segue, give it some identifier string "id".
6. Call performSegue with the ID you set will cause the table view to appear as it is in the new view controller you created.

The advantage to this approach is that your table view can be designed in it's view controller and wont clutter up the original view controller in a storyboard. Just my thoughts, you seem to be doing things programatically so I'm not sure if it's suitable to your use case but I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on where you are showing the tableview. I mean when you tap button, if you are navigating to a new controller with tableview, the delegate should be in the new controller. Or if you are showing the tableview in the same controller, the delegates will be in BasicVC. I think the collection cell has only the button. 
This is my understanding. Someone please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: I have to show table view in collection cell . different table for different collection view cell .

Comment: Then you can add a tableview as IBOutlet in collectionview cell and implement the delegate and datasource methods in the cell.  You can create a method in the collection view cell to pass the datasource required to load the tablew . Call the custom method from BasicVC in collectionview cellFoRow delegate method.